# one's complement ~ operator in c does not flip bits correctly?

Tags: c, binary, unary-operator

I have a chunk of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char i = 0b00000010; //2
    printf("%d", ~i);
}
```

if unary operator `~` flips all bits, `~i` should be equal to `0b11111101`
which is `-125`, but my code gives me output of `-3` which in binary is `0b00000011`.
Can some one please explain me why?

Comment: `11111101` is `-3`

Comment: Please learn about two's complement too.

Comment: It works just fine

Comment: Note that the `0b` notation for binary is in C++14, and not in C++11 or C11.  Because it is in C++14, many C compilers de facto support it, but it is officially a non-standard extension in C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers (which is what your machine uses most likely):

`0b11111101` is -3, not -125.

`0b10000011` would be -125 while `0b00000011` would be 3.

You seem to be assuming [sign-magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation), which is very uncommon.

The `~` operator flips all bits, but what those bits mean for negative numbers depends on your system. C allows three different representations: sign-magnitude, [ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement), and two's complement. In practice, two's complement is almost always used.

---

Also, C can't really operate on `char`s. When you try to use a `char` value in an expression, it gets promoted to `int` first. So what's actually going on in `~i` is:

- The value of `i` is read (`char` 2).
- It is converted to `int` (`int` 2).
- All bits are flipped (`int` `0b1111111....111101`, depending on how many bits your `int`s have (typically 32 or 64)).
- The bits are interpreted according to two's complement representation, corresponding to -3.

In this case the result is the same as if you'd done the operation on `char` first, then converted the result to `int`, so it makes no difference, but this is how C does it.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that in `~i`, `i` is promoted to `int` first